# ngFor cannot find a differ supporting object ... using BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Getting back to learning Angular and extending the Tour of Heroes tutorial. I have a shared data service that loads data into a BehaviorSubject. The issue is that when I try to iterate the data with *ngFor, I get the "cannot find a differ supporting object" error. From all the other questions, I get that it is trying to bind to an object and not an Array, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why. Or what object needs to get converted into an Array.

I am using Angular 5.0.5. Interestingly enough, this was working with Angular 4 but apparently I have broken something in the upgrade.

Any thoughts on what I did wrong? Besides everything. :D lol

This is my service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Hero } from '../models/hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';
    private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Hero[]>([]);

    private http: HttpClient;

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    public getLoadingStream(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
    }
    public getDataStream(): Observable<Hero[]> {
        return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public load(): void {
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);
        this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).subscribe(data => {
            this.dataSubject.next(data);
            this.loadingSubject.next(false);
        });
    }

    public search(term: string): void {
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);
        this.http
            .get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.dataSubject.next(data);
                this.loadingSubject.next(false);
        });
    }
}
```

List Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { HeroService } from '../../services/hero.service';
import { Hero } from '../../models/hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-list.component.css']
})
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {

  private dataSubscription: Subscription;
  private loadingSubscription: Subscription;

  private heroService: HeroService;

  heroes: Hero[] = [];
  isLoading: boolean;

  @Output()
  public onHeroSelected = new EventEmitter<Hero>();

  constructor(heroService: HeroService) {
    this.heroService = heroService;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingSubscription = this.heroService.getLoadingStream()
        .subscribe(loading => {
            this.isLoading = loading;
        });

    this.dataSubscription = this.heroService.getDataStream()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.heroes = data;
        });
  }

  ngOnDestory() {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.loadingSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this.onHeroSelected.emit(hero);
  }
}
```

List template

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">Loading ...</div>

<div *ngIf="!isLoading" class="ui relaxed divided list">
  <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes"  class="item" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="ui blue circular label">{{ hero.id }}</span>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">{{ hero.name }}</a>
      <div class="description">...</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looking really fast, I think it's because your service is async, so when your data `isLoading` is false it will try to display and iterate over your array. But in that moment, your array isn't set because it's async.  try to update from `*ngIf=!isLoading` to `*ngIf=!isLoading && heroes > 0`

Comment: Replace `this.dataSubject.next(data);` by `console.log(data); this.dataSubject.next(data);`. What is being logged to the console? Is it really an array?

Comment: @JBNizet yes, the data is an Array with 10 elements.

Comment: Prove it. Post the result that is logged in the console. If it's easier to copy and paste, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`.

Comment: @JBNizet {"data":[{"id":11,"name":"Batman"},{"id":12,"name":"Superman"},{"id":13,"name":"Spiderman"},{"id":14,"name":"Thor"},{"id":15,"name":"Wolverine"},{"id":16,"name":"Wonder Woman"},{"id":17,"name":"Captain America"},{"id":18,"name":"Iron Man"},{"id":19,"name":"The Hulk"},{"id":20,"name":"Duke"}]}

Comment: @sheplu If I add the && heroes > 0 the error does not occur but the list is never rendered. So the two subjects are out of sync. I was trying to signal when the loading was complete, but perhaps I have over complicated things ...

Comment: So it's not an array. It's an object. The value of the property `data` of the object is an array. An array starts with `[`. An object starts with `{`.

Comment: @JBNizet AAARRRGGGHHHH ! Good grief. Changing the for to  *ngFor="let hero of heroes.data" solved it. Can you post that as the answer. How do I make sure you get rep for that.

Comment: That fixes it, but it's really really not the appropriate solution. And it will fail if you compile with the AOT mode. getDataStream's return type is Observable<Hero[]>, and you use `.get<Hero[]>` so it should return an Observable<Hero[]>. With the code as is, the actual concrete type is Observable<{ data: Hero[] }>, and the http call should be `.get<{data: Hero[]>>. So, fix the return type, or use the map() operator to actually return an Observable<Hero[]>, by extracting the array out of the object before emitting it.

Comment: Wow this was quite the adventure. I was stuck on where the "data" object was coming from. It dawned on me finally (have not been in this project in a few months) that I was using the in-memory-web-api. Revisiting that, I realized that it was encapsulating the response in the data object. It was pure coincidence that my subscription return type was named "data". :S Ugh. lol

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining a function that returns an observable, shouldn't you be defining a property that is in fact an observable? For example:

**Service**

`public heroDataStream: Observable<Hero[]> = this.dataSubject.asObservable();`

Then you would subscribe directly to `heroDataStream`. Thats typically how I go about converting BehaviorSubjects into observables rather than wrapping them in a new function.

You might be running into a cold vs hot issue with the Observable not being created until the subscription is called since its definition is within the function. In other words its cold. You want its declaration to take place right away, meaning it needs to be hot and ready to go. So defining it as a property within your service declares it with the service. I could be wrong, this is definitely scratching the boundary of my depth of knowledge when it comes to RxJs and how everything gets spooled up.

Comment: I am not sure it matters, although I don't have a really good grasp on observable yet. Its my understanding that they are "cold" until subscribe is called. Regarding the property vs method, its just a personal style.

Comment: I suspect that your `heros` is getting an observable assigned to it, rather than the data you want. You should console log it out and see what you are actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I hate answering my own questions, but this was a big "d'oh".

The root cause of the issue was that I was using a the In-Memory-Web-API and did not realize that it was encapsulating the response in a data object.

So the error message was correct, it was trying to iterate over an object {data: [] } instead of an array.

Upgrading the In-Memory-Web-API and putting false in the data encapsulation

```
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {dataEncapsulation: false})
```

resolved the issue.

Huge thanks to JB Nizet for pointing me in the right direction!